# why does setting the PrimaryGroupId revert my group membership?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to add a new user to a specific group, set the PrimaryGroupID, and remove them from "domain users".  However, the moment I set the ID, it removes them from the group.  Any ideas?

```
internal Boolean CreateAdUser(User user, String password)
{
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(userContainerContext, user.UserId, password, true);
    userPrincipal.SamAccountName = user.UserId;
    userPrincipal.DisplayName = user.FullName;
    userPrincipal.GivenName = user.FirstName;
    userPrincipal.Surname = user.LastName;
    userPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = user.UserId + "@domain";
    userPrincipal.SetPassword(password);
    userPrincipal.PasswordNeverExpires = true;
    //create user
    userPrincipal.Save();
    //for thoroughness and to ensure I'm not dealing with a cache
    userPrincipal.Dispose();

    // at this point, I've verified the user exists.

    GroupPrincipal domainUsers;
    GroupPrincipal targetUsersGrp;

    //fetch fresh copy from AD
    userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, user.UserId);
    targetUsersGrp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, "MyUserGroup");

    //add user to my group
    targetUsersGrp.Members.Add(userPrincipal);
    targetUsersGrp.Save();
    //again, to be thorough
    userPrincipal.Dispose();
    targetUsersGrp.Dispose();

    // at this point, I can see the user is in the group and has "memberOf" set.

    //fetch fresh copy from AD
    userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, user.UserId);
    targetUsersGrp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, "MyUserGroup");
    object primaryGroupToken = getPrimaryGroupId((DirectoryEntry)targetUsersGrp.GetUnderlyingObject());

    //set primary group id on user - this has to be done through DirectoryEntry class calls
    DirectoryEntry userDirectoryEntry = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject();
    userDirectoryEntry.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "primaryGroupID", primaryGroupToken });
    userDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();

    // It's at this point where things go wrong.  The user is no longer listed in "MyUserGroup", and the "memberOf"
    // now shows it's in "Domain Users"; *however* the PrimaryGroupId *is* changed!

    //remove user from domain users - this doesn't seem to work, but I'm not there yet.
    domainUsers = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(rootContext, "Domain Users");
    domainUsers.Members.Remove(userPrincipal);

    return true;
}
object getPrimaryGroupId(DirectoryEntry de)
{
    de.RefreshCache(new[] { "primaryGroupToken" });
    return de.Invoke("Get", new object[] { "primaryGroupToken" });
}
```

Comment: *The user is no longer listed in "MyUserGroup"* - How are you determining that? Are you sure the change just hasn't replicated yet?

Comment: I'm looking at the changes through LDAP Browser.  It's possible that it's not replicating, but all the other changes appear immediately with a refresh.

Comment: That's easy to check. Just wait 15-20 minutes and see if it has taken effect. Or look at `((DirectoryEntry) userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject()).Options.GetCurrentServerName()` to see which domain controller you're connected to when you made the change, and make sure you read from the same one.

Comment: *remove user from domain users - this doesn't seem to work* - Users are usually part of `Domain Users` by way of the `primaryGroupId`. If the `primaryGroupId` was `513` (the `primaryGroupToken` of `Domain Users`) then changing the `primaryGroupId` removes the user from `Domain Users`.

Comment: My is the user appears to be moving from {"mygroup", 513} to {"domain users", 13566}.  It's like the user's membership is getting reverted, and yet the group id is set correctly.

Comment: Did you reverse those numbers by mistake? `513` is always `Domain Users`.

Comment: No, that's my point.  Create user -> add to group (still 513) -> set PrimaryGroupId (becomes 13566, but no longer in group).

Answer (score 2):

I describe this in more detail in [an article I wrote](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html), but when a group and a user are on the same domain, there are two ways that the user can be considered a member of that group:

1. The user's `distinguishedName` is in the group's `member` attribute, or
2. The user's `primaryGroupId` is set to the `primaryGroupToken` of the group.

But you won't *see* both. That's what's happening. I just tested this in our environment now.

When you do this:

```
targetUsersGrp.Members.Add(userPrincipal);
```

The effect is that the user's DN is added to the group's `member` attribute.

Now, if you then set the user's `primaryGroupId` to the `primaryGroupToken` of the group, it will do it, but it also hides the user from the `member` attribute. I say "hides", because:

1. If you change the `primaryGroupId` back to something else, the user appears back in the `member` attribute of the group.
2. You cannot set the `primaryGroupId` to a group that the user is not already a member of via the `members` attribute.

So if you want to set the primary group, you must add the user to the `member` attribute of the group *first*, then set the `primaryGroupId`, which is exactly what you're doing.

(This is something I haven't experimented with before, so I learned something here. I'm going to add this information to my article.)

Yes, the user no longer shows in the `member` attribute of the group, but it is inaccurate to say that the user is no longer a member of the group. The user is still a member of the group.

Comment: I see!  In other words, the `primaryGroupId` attribute is being used to indicate membership _instead of_ `memberOf`.  That's why, when the user is first created, it is not a `memberOf` the `Domain Users`, but is after changing the group id.

Comment: So, my last step would be to remove the user from the `Domain Users`, because changing the `primaryGroupId` does not revoke that membership.  However, when I do a `domainUsers.Save();` I get "Access denied".  Is there a special permission needed for this?

Comment: That depends on your domain. The `Domain Users` group is in the built-in `Users` container.